# google daily search trend scraping

Tags: python, r, web-scraping

I've taught myself web scraping and would like to scrape data from Google daily search trend here: https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily?geo=US
The data would include search keywords, their ranks, search frequencies on a daily basis.

I tried scraping with R using rvest library at the beginning but extracting command scraped empty data. I guess html structure of the website is too complex than rvest is based? So I'd like to learn better way that can apply to the website.

I searched for some information specific to the daily search scraping but couldn't find as most posts were concerned with extracting Google Trend data rather than the daily search.

What would be an effective way to extract data from the website, or more general, this kind of website? I'm happy to learn any other tools than R and have basic knowledge in Python and Javascript. If anyone could give me a hint, then I will dig into it but at the moment I have no idea even where to start.

Thanks,

Comment: Great R package for google trends    https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtrendsR/gtrendsR.pdf

If you want to do the work yourself try using a Selenium web crawler - more info here (Python) - https://guygw.com/2018/05/15/scraping-google-trends-with-selenium-and-python/

Comment: I looked into the package as well but couldn't find it useful as it focuses on Google Trend rather than the Daily Search? Please let me know if I miss anything.

Comment: For example, the package extract data for a specific keyword that you select but what I'd like to extract is general keywords that are searched daily.

Comment: I misread the question, I see. I think your best bet is setting up a Selenium web crawler. There are great packages in almost every language for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the HTML using the 'inpect element' tool in firefox.

Essentially, we can see that every element you want to scrape from the webpage can be distinguished easily based on the tooltip :

[image: The tooltip used]

Given that, we can use selenium to scrape the webpage to retrive this information.

(Install it first with `pip3 install -U selenium` and install your favorite webdiver [from the links here](http://pypi.org/project/selenium))

Start a browser and direct it to the google trends page using something similar to

```
╰─ ipython3
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 29 2018, 20:13:13)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from selenium import webdriver

In [2]: browser = webdriver.Firefox()
   ...: browser.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily?geo=US')
```

You should now see something similar to this :

[image: What you see on starting selenium webdriver]

Again, using the inspect element tool, get the class of the div that contain every element to scrape :

[image: What to scrape]

We need to find the div with a class named `feed-list-wrapper`.

```
In [3]: list_div = browser.find_element_by_class_name("feed-list-wrapper")

In [4]: list_div
Out[4]: <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="b889702e-7e2b-7448-9180-c9fb3d1ff641", element="cad96530-3444-9d4f-a8e8-b7da780f5751")>
```

Once done, just get the list of the div details :

```
In [5]: details_divs = list_div.find_elements_by_class_name("details")
```

And, for example, get the title (you should understand the code by now)

```
In [6]: for detail_div in details_divs:
    ...:     print(detail_div.find_element_by_class_name("details-top").find_element_by_xpath("div/span/a").text)
    ...:
Captain Marvel
Celia Barquin Arozamena
Yom Kippur
Lethal White
National Cheeseburger Day 2018
Ind vs HK
Mario Kart
Barcelona
Emilia Clarke
Elementary
Angela Bassett
Lenny Kravitz
Lil Uzi Vert
Handmaid's Tale
Mary Poppins Returns trailer
Hannah Gadsby
```

Another example, to get the view count :

```
In [7]: for detail_div in details_divs:
    ...:     title = detail_div.find_element_by_class_name("details-top").find_element_by_xpath("div/span/a").text
    ...:     search_count = detail_div.find_element_by_xpath('..').find_element_by_class_name("search-count-title").text
    ...:     print("Title : {title} \t\t\t Searchs : {search_count}".format(title=title, search_count=search_count))
    ...:
Title : Captain Marvel           Searchs : 500 k+
Title : Celia Barquin Arozamena              Searchs : 200 k+
Title : Yom Kippur           Searchs : 100 k+
Title : Lethal White             Searchs : 50 k+
Title : National Cheeseburger Day 2018           Searchs : 50 k+
Title : Ind vs HK            Searchs : 50 k+
Title : Mario Kart           Searchs : 50 k+
Title : Barcelona            Searchs : 50 k+
Title : Emilia Clarke            Searchs : 50 k+
Title : Elementary           Searchs : 20 k+
Title : Angela Bassett           Searchs : 20 k+
Title : Lenny Kravitz            Searchs : 20 k+
Title : Lil Uzi Vert             Searchs : 20 k+
Title : Handmaid's Tale              Searchs : 20 k+
Title : Mary Poppins Returns trailer             Searchs : 20 k+
Title : Hannah Gadsby            Searchs : 20 k+
```

You should get used to selenium quickly. If you have any doubt on the methos used here, here is a link to the [selenium docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I've got some ideas thanks to your reply. There is long way to go to get used to the selenium though. Thanks alot!

Comment: Well, selenium allow you to control the browser 'as a human could'. You can also click on elements (Here, you could click on the div with class `feed-load-more-button` to load more results for example: `browser.find_element_by_class_name('feed-load-more-button').click()`)

Comment: @Mike Remeber, almost ANY website can be scraped but some websites are trickier than others. You can use selemium as shown there, or just any other scraping lib could do the job (IE : beautifulsoup). Using selenium, you can also run some javascript in the browser, if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I started looking at Selenium. It was really big missing part. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @WayToDoor, just for an update, I've managed to complete the script as I wanted. Thanks for your help! It was really helpful. I'm pretty happy with my final script as I made a function to repeat the same thing for a few countries. However, it has one part missing which is relavant to 'load more'.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to handle 'load more' in conventional way? to let the script scrape data until load more opens n times, for instance. I know it's too general question but would be great if you could give me some small hints, where to look for. Thanks.

Comment: Search for the load more button on the page `lm= browser.find_element_by_class_name('feed-load-more-button')` and then click it ( `lm.click()`)

Repeat N times, parse the page after

Comment: Hi @WayToDoor, thanks a lot!! That totally makes sense. I will work in that way as you suggested. Cheers!